# Adding Xamarin.Forms to an existing Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a Xamarin.Forms page to an existing Xamarin Android app.

I'm struggling to figure out how to mix native Xamarin Android pages and Xamarin.Forms pages.

All the articles and examples I have seen describe either Forms or Xamarin apps and not a hybrid of the two.

The best idea I have read about so far is to add a native stub and replace the content with  Xamarin.Forms content but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

**Update**

I'm using MvvmCross so my android view is inherited from MvxActivity. I have a StackLayout containing views using Xamarin.Forms. How do I get XF to convert to android code so I can use with SetContentView?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new **Xamarin.Forms** project, for instance with a *SharedProject* approach, it will create the launcher project and initial class file that will be executed for you for each platform.

For instance on **Android** this is in *MainActivity.cs*.  If you look inside this file you will notice that it inherits from **AndroidActivity** which in turn inherits from **Activity**, which is the typical class used on activities.

So you have two options available for you to create a mixed hybrid solution:-

1) Inherit from **AndroidActivity** in your *platform-specifc* *stub-page* should you want to display **Xamarin.Forms** content, or alternatively

2) Inherit from **Activity**, and do the same as usual.

If you want to display a **Xamarin.Forms** page from the *stub-page* you can then just use some boiler-plate code such as the following in the **OnCreate** method:-

```
 SetPage({some class that returns a Xamarin.Forms.Page object, i.e. ContentPage});
```

You can then use the normal navigation that is specific to **Android** to either display a **Xamarin.Forms** page or a platform-specific **Activity** page.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Unfortunately I'm using MvvmCross and have an MvxActivity which does not convert to AndroidActivity. I can get a StackLayout and can SetContentView in my android page but how do I convert the StackLayout to something android will recognise?

Comment: There's a sample of using both in http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2014/07/xamarinforms-and-mvvmcross.html